# Deciding between Activity Context or Application Context to Instantiate SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: sqliteopenhelper, android-context

I am new to Android development (to development overall to be frank), and as such I have been reading Commonsware Busy Coder's guide. While reading through the SQLite section, there are a couple things that are not %100 clear to me. Below is what I believe is going on as well as some questions. Please correct me if I am wrong in my thought process.

The author suggests that if you are going to use a database from more than just one Activity in your application, you shouldn't use the Context reference from each Activity to instantiate the **SQLiteOpenHelper**. Instead, you should use `getApplicationContext()` provided by Activity.

By doing so, he uses the fact that `getApplicationContext()` retrieves the singleton instance of Context created soon after the application process begins. Here is where my question arises. I think that if I were to use the Context provided by the Activity(this keyword) when instantiating **SQLiteOpenHelper**, each Activity will create its own instance of **SQLiteOpenHelper**. It appears to me that just using the Activity's Context does not inform the Application Context that there already is an instance of the SQLiteHelper created, and hence, it creates a new one instead of re-using the existing one. Is my thinking correct?

I think of Context (and correct me if I am wrong) as the developer's "gateway" to get information and resources provided by the Android OS (i.e. getting hold of a system service via `getSystemService()`). But doing so using this (from an Activity) or using `getApplicationContext()` has different implications. Using this, will get an instance of Context which is "local" to your current Activity, but using `getApplicationContext()` references the whole application. If this is correct, does it mean that when I pass a reference to `getApplicationContext()` to the **SQLiteOpenHelper's** constructor it will let my whole Application know that there is an instance of my **SQLiteOpenHelper** already created. How does **SQLiteOpenHelper** let the Application know about this? does it use some static method like public/private static dbCreated(Context context){//let context know there is an instance of this running} to let the Application know?

I am sorry if this is confusing.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if it is confusing. The questions are at the end of the third and fourth paragraphs.

Comment: It sure is. I am looking for a question, that can be answered within the scope of SO. Yours is too broad so far.

Comment: What I am asking is if my thought process is correct. Why when I use the Activity's own context to instantiate the database helper class Android creates a new instance every time and when I use getApplicationContext() it only creates just one. Sorry for the confusion. This is my first post...

Comment: cause appContext is single instance for the whole app (like singleton)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Think by now I do have a better understanding of the concept of Context. I would like to share a link I found that clarifies this topic. http://t.co/9R0bPWiKc5

Answer (score 2):

To your second question, if I understand it correctly, Context is some kind of a [Registry of Singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern). So **SQLiteOpenHelper** is just created and tied to the context given to it. Everything that uses this context to acquire **SQLiteOpenHelper** will get that tied instance.